# checkvalidity always returns true for required field

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field and a button. When the button is clicked, I wanted to invoke HTML style field validation error message. Due to this reason, I wrapped up the input and the field in a form.

```
    <form id="frmShippingHeader">
     <input name="trailerNumber" id="trailerNumber" class="form-control fireChange" type="text"  aria-describedby="enter Part Number" placeholder="Trailer Number" required>
     <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnCreateShipping" onClick="createShippingOrder()">Create Shipping Order</button>
   </form>
```

Using my javascript I wanted to check if the form is valid or invalid. If the form is valid I will do prevent default and there is no need for error message. If the form is invalid howerver, I wanted to not do prevent default. However, even when I leave the input field empty and click the button the `blnFormValidity` returns true

```
$("#btnCreateShipping").click(function(e){

    blnFormValidity= $('#frmShippingHeader')[0].checkValidity()
    console.log(blnFromValidity)

    if(blnFormValidity==true){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false
    }

})
```

Comment: I think the problem is you're adding [0] in a selector which only gets one form (not an array)

Comment: If I remove 0 i get `$(...).checkValidity is not a function` error

Comment: ops mistake, I'll see if I can solve and get back to you

Comment: console.log(blnFromValidity) spelling mistake here

Answer (score 0):

You have spelling mistake here

```
blnFormValidity= $('#frmShippingHeader')[0].checkValidity()
console.log(blnFromValidity)

blnFromValidity is different than blnFormValidity
```

other than this You can use jquery validate plugin for validation. [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

then you can directly check form validation

```
$("#btnCreateShipping").click(function(e){

    console.log($("#frmShippingHeader").validate());
 })
```

Which is quite easy and can provide more features to you. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and printed `true`

```
$("#btnCreateShipping").click(function(e){

    const blnFormValidity= $('#frmShippingHeader')[0].checkValidity();
    console.log(blnFormValidity);

    if(blnFormValidity === true){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false
    }

});

function createShippingOrder  () {
    alert('working')
}
```

If you want to write 100% valid code, Use [webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

Answer (score 0):

Correcting your existing code:
It is just spelling mistake as everybody mentioned for your variable. So just correcting that thing will work. 
**Addition**: in your html form, you are invoking method on `onclick` event, keep in mind that if you don't have anything special to do on your `createShippingOrder(...)` method, remove it otherwise you may not get your desired result in order as event binding-`click` and calling method on `onclick` will cause you problem like happening thing in unexpected order. To resolve that, you can gather your click event's functionality inside your method or vice-versa. Check [Your corrected code-jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3df96axs/).
You can also use JQuery form validator which is pretty much handy like this:

```
 <form id="frmShippingHeader">
     <input name="trailerNumber" id="trailerNumber" class="form-control fireChange" type="text"  aria-describedby="enter Part Number" placeholder="Trailer Number" >
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnCreateShipping" >Create Shipping Order</button>
   </form>
```

JQuery form validation:

```
$("#frmShippingHeader").validate({
  rules: {
    trailerNumber:
    {
        required: true,
      number:true
    },

  },
  messages: {
   trailerNumber:
    {
        required: "Please trailer number",
      number:"Must be a number"
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My case.
When the filds was disabled, the return ever TRUE...

```
let formCad = $("#form-cadastromodal");
if (formCad[0].checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
}
formCad.addClass('was-validated'); // important to display validation on form
```

Good Luck

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).